# Linear Regression - how to predict the estimated relative performance?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, prediction

> Paul need a laptop that is fast enough. One of the main parameter of computers which he must focus on is CPU. In this project we need to forecast performance of CPU which is characterized in terms of cycle time and memory capacity and so on.

It is Linear Regression problem and you should predict the Estimated Relative Performance column.

I am new in Python. Could anybody help me with the code for this task?

[CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kZMau73A7P03gXWJ73ju41XkiX7BmK-F/view?usp=sharing) (on Google Drive)

This is what I have done. But probably I did not understand the case.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = pd.read_csv("Computer_Hardware.csv")
data
data.describe()

y = data["Machine Cycle Time in nanoseconds"]
x1 = data["Estimated Relative Performance"]
plt.scatter(x1,y)
plt.xlabel("Estimated Relative Performance", fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel("Machine Cycle Time in nanoseconds", fontsize = 20)
plt.show()

x = sm.add_constant(x1)
x = sm.add_constant(x1)
results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
results.summary()
```

Comment: I think you might be better served with a tutorial that explains what you have to do and why.

Comment: Does your model only use one independent variable? Or Does it use more of the values in the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any fitted model from `statsmodels` you can extract predicted values with method predict() and then add them to your frame.

```
data['predicted'] = results.predict()
```

[image]

Maybe your model needs more work, for now, it only uses a variable and maybe you will get a better prediction with another model that uses more variables.

```
y = b0 + b1 * x1
```

According to the text "... CPU which is characterized in terms of cycle time and memory capacity and so on" is the problem.

A proposal will be to extend your models using `statsmodels` API to write a formula. In your case I like to remove all spaces in columns names before.

```py
# Rename columns without spaces
old_columns = data.columns
new_columns = [col.replace(' ', '_') for col in old_columns]
data = data.rename(columns={old:new for old, new in zip(old_columns, new_columns)})

# Fit a model using more variables
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm2

formula = ('Estimated_Relative_Performance ~ ', 
           'Machine_Cycle_Time_in_nanoseconds + ',
           'Maximum_Main_Memory_in_kilobytes + ', 
           'Cache_Memory_in_Kilobytes + ', 
           'Maximum_Channels_in_Units')
formula = ' '.join(formula)
print(formula)

results2 = sm2.ols(formula, data).fit()
results2.summary()

data['predicted2'] = results2.predict()
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras is one of the easiest libraries to use if you don't have much experience in Python. This is a good tutorial: https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/

Answer (score 0):

I studied some blogs regarding the topic, and came with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib inline

raw_data = pd.read_csv("Computer_Hardware.csv")

x = raw_data[['Machine Cycle Time in nanoseconds',
       'Minimum Main Memory in Kilobytes', 'Maximum Main Memory in kilobytes',
       'Cache Memory in Kilobytes', 'Minimum Channels in Units',
       'Maximum Channels in Units', 'Published Relative Performance']]

y = raw_data['Estimated Relative Performance']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(x_train, y_train)

print(model.coef_)

print(model.intercept_)

pd.DataFrame(model.coef_, x.columns, columns = ['Coeff'])

predictions = model.predict(x_test)

plt.hist(y_test - predictions)

from sklearn import metrics

metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, predictions)

metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions)

np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions))
```